# A table to hold History of changes for two fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2014

I have a table which holds a Person (details). Two of the fields, we have a requirement to store and show the history of the changes. They are 'IsActive BIT' and 'IsIdle BIT'.

At the moment, they're fields within the Person table.

The requirement is to be able to display when the person was active, and when they were idle. As well as who set those values. (All tales have a LastUpdatedBy and CreatedBy column).

My plan is to use a PersonHistory table, with the PersonID *FK to the Person*, and the IsActive and IsIdle columns, and the CreatedBy and LastUpdatedBy columns. And a 'EffectiveFrom' DATETIME.

So when we create a person, we add a row to the history with the IsActive and IsIdle values, user and the PersonID.

To display a person, we have to do an (Untidy?) selection of the person record, and then join to the last record for that person in the history table. INNER JOIN .. SELECT TOP 1 * FROM History, using a ROW_NUMBER? Might be slow.

When editing 'IsActive', we need to add a new row with the PersonID and the new IsActive (and/or IsIdle) value. Actually, we need to store both. A row will only get written when these values change. Which means we'll need to do a pre-save check to see if the values changed.

Does this seem like a standard way to handle this requirement - or is there a better more common approach?

Comment: You could save the values in the Person table as well as in the History table, and eliminate the need for the join. You also might want to look into [Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/cc645937.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You might try this method before changing the data structure:

```
select p.*, ph.*
from Person p outer apply
     (select top 1 ph.*
      from personhistory ph
      where ph.personid = p.personid
      order by ph.effectivefrom desc
     ) ph;
```

For performance, you want an index on `personhistory(personid, effetivefrom)`.